How to prove this inequality with parameter $a$?
Given $ \text{0 < } a \text{ < 1}$ and $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_N \geq 2$. Then
$$
\frac{\sum_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l }{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^a } \leq x_1^{1-a} + \frac{2}{a x_1^a}
$$
Proof: By induction over $N$. It is obviously true for $N=1$. Assume it holds for $N$ and prove for $N+1$.
I've been trying all night by induction or arguing the optimal $a$, but nothing's working. This lemma is in Appendix of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-019-03618-x

Please check this example (if I am right):
Let $a = \frac{1}{15}$, and $N = 6$, and
$x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = 50$,
and $x_5 = x_6 = 2$. We have
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6}{(x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6)^a} \approx 65.52909451,
$$
and
$$x_1^{1-a} + \frac{2}{a x_1^a} \approx 61.63470477.$$

Given $ \text{0 < } \alpha \text{ < 1}$ and $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_N \geq 2$. Assuming the statement holds for $N$, we have
$$
\frac{\sum_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l }{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^a } \leq x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}
$$
Modifying the expression slightly
$$
\frac{\sum_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l + x_{N+1} - x_{N+1}}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^\alpha \cdot \frac{x_{N+1}^\alpha}{x_{N+1}^\alpha}} \leq x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}
$$
$$
\frac{x_{N+1}^\alpha \left( \sum_{1 \leq l \leq N+1} x_l - x_{N+1} \right)}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N+1} x_l^\alpha} \leq x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}
$$
$$
\therefore \frac{\sum_{1 \leq l \leq N+1} x_l}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N+1} x_l^\alpha} \leq \frac{1}{x_{N+1}^\alpha} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} \right) + \frac{x_{N+1}}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N+1} x_l^\alpha}
$$
We need to show that the left hand side is actually less than $x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}$. The right side of the expression can be written as
$$
\frac{1}{x_{N+1}^\alpha} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} \right) + \frac{x_{N+1}}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^\alpha} \frac{1}{x_{N+1}^\alpha}
$$
Pulling out the $\frac{1}{x_{N+1}^{\alpha}}$ term from both the expressions
$$
\frac{1}{x_{N+1}^\alpha} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} + \frac{x_{N+1}}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^\alpha} \right)
$$
Note that since $x_{N+1} \leq x_N$, the above expression is
$$
\leq \frac{1}{x_{N+1}^\alpha} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} + \frac{x_{N}}{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^\alpha} \right)
$$
Once again using the statement for N, we have
$$
\frac{\sum_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l }{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^a } \leq x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}
\Rightarrow \frac{x_N }{\prod_{1 \leq l \leq N} x_l^a } \leq x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha}
$$
Applying this in the expression, we get that our expression is
$$
\leq \frac{2}{x_{N+1}^\alpha} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} \right)
$$
Note that since $2\leq x_{N+1} \Rightarrow \frac{2}{x_{N+1}^{\alpha}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{\alpha-1}}$, the above expression is
$$
\leq {2^{1-\alpha}} \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} \right)
$$
Since $0<\alpha<1$, hence $0<1 - \alpha<1$, so $2^{1-\alpha}<1$ which gives us our desired expression
$$
\leq \left( x_1^{1-\alpha} + \frac{2}{\alpha x_1^\alpha} \right)
$$

When $1-\alpha>0$, $2^{1-\alpha}>1$.

@Trinifold yes I realised it yesterday while trying to sleep. I'll try again today
